# Usage of -name '*.extention' -or -name '*extention' with find command

Tags: linux, find, command, delete-file

I am trying to delete all files in a folder except multiple video extentions.
What's missing in my command line?

```
find /to/path/ -type f -not \(-name '*.mp4' -or -name '*.flv' -or -name '*.3gp' -or -name '*.mov' -or -name '*.asf' -or -name '*.mpg' -or -name '*.avi' -or -name '*.mpeg' -or -name '*.wmv' -or -name '*.rm' -or -name '*.dat' -or -name '*.mkv' -or -name '*.vob' -or -name '*.m2v' -or -name '*.f4v' -or -name '*.m4v' -or -name '*.m2t' -or -name '*.mts' -or -name '*.webm' -or -name '*.ts' \) -delete
```

I am getting:

```
find: paths must precede expression
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to separate parentheses from expression terms.  That is change `\(-name` to `\( -name`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you over complicating things. Just use `rm -v !(*.mp4|*.flv|*.3gp|*.mov)` you can add more extensions, but I was to lazy to do that.